# EventLogEntry.TimeGenerated returns totally wrong date

Tags: c#, event-log

I've been writing a c# app which writes logs to a file on physical disk, but i've noticed a strange behavior of a TimeGenerated property - the local date on a computer is xx.xx.2056(don't ask why), but the value of the property gives xx.xx.1920 year and the time doesn't match either.

Here is the code:

```
using (EventLog log = new EventLog("Application", "."))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("events.log"))
    {
        foreach (EventLogEntry e in log.Entries)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("{0} : {1} : {2}", e.TimeGenerated, e.EntryType, e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have to ask.... *why* is the local date 2056? is that the lesser-known UTC+375k timezone?

Comment: we're testing our apps to see how it's going to work, i guess it's called future date testing or something like that. Well, i can use some other year not far from 2056 and still it will give me the same result.

Comment: Is this problem related to a particular date range? Or does it always occur regardless?

Comment: @bytefire, it rolls in when local date is +n from the actual one, where n > 20 or so.

Comment: What format is used to store the `TimeGenerated` on disk?  The `DateTime` type is valid from `00:00:00 01-Jan-0001` through `23:59:59 31-Dec-9999` (actuall 1ns before `00:00:00 1-Jan-10000`)so it's most likely the intermediate format that is tripping you up.

Comment: It will be helpful to know the threshold date, if possible. That might carry some clues. Also googling that date with related keywords may return some useful results.

Comment: @bytefire, thanks for a suggestion, i will find that out today.

Comment: @Corey, the local date format is 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss', i know date can mess day with month, but i've never seen it changin the year in any kind of way. What do you mean by 'intermediate format'?

Comment: Oh, it's an EventLog... forget my prior comment.  This is a strange one, since the Windows Event Log uses a SYSTEMTIME structure to store the timestamps, and that should be valid for another 28,800 years or so.  I presume that the timestamps displayed in the Event Viewer on the test machine are valid?

Comment: @Corey, no sign of the mistake in the Event Viewer - you're right.

Answer (score 0):

test on win2003 server sp2, local date 2056 (correct date in event viewer):

```
            ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope();
            ObjectQuery oQuery = new ObjectQuery("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent where Logfile = 'Application' and type ='Error'");
            ManagementObjectSearcher oS = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ms, oQuery);
            ManagementObjectCollection oCollection = oS.Get();
            var i2 = oCollection.Cast<ManagementObject>().First();
            DateTime timewritten = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(i2["TimeWritten"].ToString());
```

I get 1920

Comment: How does this answer the question?